# How do I add ability for child image to overwrite arg from base docker image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

So I want to have an arg, but also a way to overwrite this arg via onbuild. Something like this in the base dockerfile:

```
ARG randvar
ONBUILD ARG randvar
ENV randvar=$randvar
```

In my child dockerfile I have

```
FROM baseimage
ARG randvar
RUN echo $randvar
```

But I can't seem to overwrite the ARG for some reason.
This is my docker-compose file.

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  basec:
    build:
      context: ./dir
      dockerfile: base.Dockerfile 
      args:
        randvar: "this is orig arg"

  childc:
    build:
      context: ./dir
      dockerfile: child.Dockerfile
      args:
        randvar: "this is new arg"
```

First I run `docker-compose run basec` then `docker-compose run childc`
My echo statement is showing "this is orig arg" instead of "this is new arg". Thx